# Copying data from one cell to another based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a heat sheet that updates names according to position.. The Top 2 from each heat go to round 2 and are seeded into heats according to position..

So H1 R1 winner goes go R2 H1   So in Example below  I need to move Deee to R2 H1

So Heat 1 Round 1 would be 
|COLOUR | NAME | POSITION|
|Red    | Abbb | 3       |
|White  | Bccc | 2       |
|Yellow | Deee | 1       |
|Blue   | Fggg | 4       |

Round 2 Heat 1 would be
|COLOUR | NAME | POSITION|
|Red    | Deee |         |
|White  | Bccc |         |
|Yellow |      |         |
|Blue   |      |         |

EG If position in (c2:C5) = "1" then name in "b2" is copied to "g5"

Comment: Will there always be only four names?

Comment: Each heat is only 4 names and there could be 40 names in a round , ie 10 heats of 4

Comment: Can you please provide an example with more than one heat please.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for. Just an idea...

Assuming your first heat table is in columns A to C with first row being header and the next rows data and column 3 holding the position.

You could have a second heat table with e.g. column "E" holding the new position numbers and column "F" the follwing formular

```
=OFFSET($A$1;MATCH(E1;$C$2:$C$5;0);1)
```

shows the name in the new heat table according to position in the original table.

```
   A   |   B   |   C  |  D  |   E   |    F    
Colour | Name  |  Pos |     |new Pos|-formular-
```

Comment: thanks @ jemmy , I will try that , I have uploaded the layout here , https://www.dropbox.com/s/infky3lc0gvd6ji/heat%20sheet.PNG?dl=0 it makes more sense seeing it all in one place.

once I know how to get it started I am good to go :) Its a knockout competition format for my surf club

Comment: Like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/pywazmmywuh8a96/2014-11-14%20Value%20of%20cell%20depending%20on%20another%20cell.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Yes that is exactly it